# How to use GreenMail test suite in play framework?

Tags: java, unit-testing, plugins, playframework, mail-server

Is it possible to use [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/) test suite in Play projects?

If so, how to use it?

Is there any plugin? (I found a GreenMail plugin for Grails but none for Play)

Or does Play support mail server testing by itself without GreenMail?

(I'm using Eclipse IDE by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use it with JUnit, you can use it with Play. The code below is just a regular play unit test:

```
public class GreenMailTest extends UnitTest {

  private GreenMail mail;

  @Before
  public void startGreenMail() {
    GreenMail greenMail = new GreenMail();
    greenMail.start();  
  }

  @Test
  public void myTestThatUsesGreenMail() {
    GreenMailUtil.sendTextEmailTest("to@localhost.com", "from@localhost.com", "subject", "body");
    assertEquals("body", GreenMailUtil.getBody(greenMail.getReceivedMessages()[0]));
  }

  @After
  public void stopGreenMail() {
    greenMail.stop();
  }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: but Eclipse doesn't recognize GreenMail keyword in my play project.

Comment: Have you configured the greenmail jars in Eclipse? Maybe you can just add it as a play dependency and then run both "play deps" and "play eclipsify".

Comment: yes, but I had forgotten to import `com.icegreen.greenmail.util.*`. and now it's solved.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the play plugin from https://github.com/alextir/play-module-greenmail